# Validate username as input is provided to textbox in jsp

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

I have a jsp form in which a user can signup by entering username and password. I have to check dynamically whether the username exists in mysql database as the username is typed into the text box. Here is a sample code:

```
<html>
<head>Sample Signup</head>
<body>
<form action="updatedb.jsp" method="post">
Username : <input type="text" name="uname">
<br>
Password : <input type="text" name="upass">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="signup">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to jsp so an elaborated answer will be more helpful. If i missed any other important info, ask me right away.

Comment: Where is the code where you attempt to validate against the database?

Comment: that's where i am confused, I want to put that validate code (in java) in onChange attribute of input tag but I am not sure how to achieve this. My database name is demo, table is login with username and password fields.

Comment: @MachMitch u need to save the usernames in the javascript and then validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java cannot respond to the client-side methods like onChange (not directly).  Those methods call Javascript. Javascript is not actually related in any way to Java; its only called that because it uses the bracket-style syntax for functions as opposed to VB-style syntax.  The only way to involve Java itself in the client-side methods would be to use Javascript to send an Ajax request to a JSP/Servlet and receive a response back. The simplest way to send an Ajax request in Javascript is with [jquery](http://jquery.com/) (a javascript library).

Comment: thanks i think jsp itself would be inefficient to achieve the task i want to